# Does Safari iOS9 returns a wrong value for window.innerHeight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, ios9

Here is my viewport meta tag :

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale = 1, minimum-scale = 1, maximum-scale = 1, width=device-width">
```

On Safari iOS 8, `window.innerHeight` and `$(window).height()` both returns the same value: 928 on an iPad.

But on Safari iOS 9, `window.innerHeight` and `$(window).height()` returns different values: respectively 1461 and 559 on an iPhone 6s running iOS 9.0 or 1154 and 905 on an iPad mini running iOS 9.1.

Is this a bug in Safari or is it intended? Where does that 1461 come from on my iPhone? Should I be using `$(window).height()` (which returns the value I want) instead of `window.innerHeight`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, i experienced the same behavior...

`Using $(window).height()` seems to work, but I guess it's better to change the meta-tag.

See [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/3la04p/psa_safari_on_ios9_has_a_media_query_bug/)

Answer (score 6):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=no">
```

adding "shrink-to-fit=no" to the viewport meta tag fixed an erroneous window.innerHeight value on resize for me -

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13510

Comment: this one should be the answer

Comment: Thanks. I got this issue on Safari iPad

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your meta tag to..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0001, minimum-scale=1.0001, maximum-scale=1.0001, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Comment: this is the solution that worked for me!! Mind explain why?

Upvoted because this hacky solution is the only thing that worked for me sans some javascript setTimeout hack.

Comment: okay after a few minutes, it broke again. 

It turned out that in mobile safari the layout event is tied with the Width and Height set to 980px and 1487px.

Comment: Works for me, what an ugly hack tho, lets hope Apple is going to fix this!